# Creating Date Dimension table using SSIS

Tags: etl, ssis

I'm new to **SSIS**.I want to extract Flight Date from excel and store it in Dimension 'Date' using SSIS.

I googled and found ways to populate other dimension tables apart from 'Date'.

In my excel source, the date is stored in `12/31/2011  12:00:00 AM` format. I want to extract the date (eg. `12/31/2011`) and then stored it in SQL table as,

- Year
- Month
- Day
- IsWeekEnd

Any hint, or any helpful link will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A date dimension is not what you describe. Take a look at what a date dimension should be: http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/calendar-date-dimension/

Comment: It would be far better to store it as a simple datetime value in your table and join an actual date dimension table to the imported table.